# get a subview back after placing it into the view

Tags: objective-c

so in my app, i click a button and i dynamically add a UITextField:

```
myRect = CGRectMake(4, viewYPos, 80, 25);
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
myTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12];
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
myTextField.delegate = self;
[myTextField addTarget:self
                action:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

[attributeScrollView addSubview:myTextField];   
[myTextField release];
```

now, how do i reference this text field? is there a way to pull it out of the view and place it back into a new textfield variable?

my only thought is to create an instance nsarray variable so i can keep their reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make myTextField an instance variable instead of local. Then, don't release it.

Comment: yep, if i need to, i'll add them (user can create X amount of them) to an nsarray to retain them, but was wondering if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Nope. Without any more info available to me, an array is probably best.